# Logging the selected from HTML list and use it as key in populating another

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

I'm trying to populate two dynamic Lists from two different JSON APIs , Where I need the first selected option to be used as the key to populate the second List.

HTML :

```
     <p>
        <input type="button" value="Fill SELECT Dropdown List with JSON" id="bt" />
    </p>

    <select id="clist" >
        <option value="">-- Select --</option>
    </select>

    <select id="plist">
    <option value="">-- Select --</option>
    </select>

    <p id="client_name"></p>
```

JS:

```
     $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#bt').click(function () {

            var url1 = "https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbx91EB9aIOXRYNmP108ZcPuEGgUqZWZli0KWdj5A3Ts0Qc6hrc/exec";
        $.getJSON(url1, function (data) {
            $.each(data, function (index, value) {
                // APPEND OR INSERT DATA TO SELECT ELEMENT.
                $('#clist').append('<option value="' + value.ID + '">' + value.Client + '</option>');
            });
        });
    });
});

    $('#clist').change(function () {

        $('#client_name').text(this.options[this.selectedIndex].text);
        var s_name=this.options[this.selectedIndex].text ;

    });



$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#clist').change(function () {

        var url2 = "https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbz91DIwPh3n4A7gtyV7iTrGxT7t23FMJES3n-ruvxHcfsFEXuBL/exec";

        $.getJSON(url2, function (data2) {
            $.each(data2, function (index2, value2) {
                // APPEND OR INSERT DATA TO SELECT ELEMENT.
                $('#plist').append('<option value="' + value2.ID + '">' + value2[s_name] + '</option>');
            });
        });
    });
});
```

I was able to log the value and make a dynamic change and it works for the element Client_name but it doesn't work when populating the second list and returns undefined.

Note :
The selected option from the first key is exactly matching the available keys in the second list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the solution for you question:

You need to just check if the key exists in **value2** array.

Running code: https://jsfiddle.net/sfhogj7a/2/

Javascript:

```
var s_name =''; // make global 
$(document).ready(function () {
        $('#bt').click(function () {

            var url1 = "https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbx91EB9aIOXRYNmP108ZcPuEGgUqZWZli0KWdj5A3Ts0Qc6hrc/exec";
        $.getJSON(url1, function (data) {
            $.each(data, function (index, value) {
                // APPEND OR INSERT DATA TO SELECT ELEMENT.
                $('#clist').append('<option value="' + value.ID + '">' + value.Client + '</option>');
            });
        });
    });
});

$('#clist').change(function () {

    $('#client_name').text(this.options[this.selectedIndex].text);
    s_name=this.options[this.selectedIndex].text ;

});

$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#clist').change(function () {
      console.log('list')
        var url2 = "https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbz91DIwPh3n4A7gtyV7iTrGxT7t23FMJES3n-ruvxHcfsFEXuBL/exec";

        $.getJSON(url2, function (data2) {
            $.each(data2, function (index2, value2) {
                // APPEND OR INSERT DATA TO SELECT ELEMENT.
                if(value2[s_name]){ // check if exists
                  $('#plist').append('<option value="' + value2.ID + '">' + value2[s_name] + '</option>');
                }
            });
        });
    });
});
```